# How to Migrate Drupal Database to Opencart?

Tags: drupal, opencart, database-migration

I have to move products, categories, attributes from Drupal Database to OpenCart. It would be ok if only tables or rows that are available in both databases are available. Is there an automated way to do this?

Comment: There is no such a tool currently, you will have to write the script :(

Comment: If you're using something like uber cart on Drupal, you can use a service like 'cart2cart' to transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't write a migration-script, a way to achieve this would be looking through the Database-Structure of both the Systems, exporting the Tables concerned from Drupal, editing them manually to fit the Scheme of Opencart and then import it into your OC-Database.

Comment: that's harder than writing a script